# Not able to write a string to libre calc using xlwt

Tags: pointers, xlwt

I need to send my Raspberry Pi's MAC address to the excel sheet using xlwt module in python.

I am already pushing the date and time and a barcode generated dynamically. Which is working fine.

But everytime I try to send the MAC address, it doesn't happen. It just shows a blank cell.

Here is my code

```
MAC = open("/sys/class/net/eth0/address').read()
workbook.write(0, 0, barcode)
workbook.write(0, 1, time)
workbook.write(0, 2, MAC)
```

Now, the barcode and time are written in the cells perfectly. But the MAC just won't write. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to your code:

`print(ascii(MAC))`

and edit your question to show the result.
Also it would be very good if you showed the workbook being created and saved.